# Dynamically change Timezone in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to change timezone of Laravel App dynamically.  What I need is the admin user will set a timezone for the entire app that will be stored in a table.  Whenever a user login that timezone will be applied to all the requests.
What I tried is; added the following code to the boot section of AppServiceProvider :

```
Config::set('app.timezone', 'Asia/Kabul');
```

Asia/Kabul will be replaced with data from table.
But it does not change time when I check in blade view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'Asia/Kabul']);
```

also execute these commands to clear cahce and config

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear
```